# Probability of points less than a fixed distance apart in a vector space

Tags: distributions, distance, norm

I have a distribution $D$ of points in a normed vector space (it's $\mathbb{R}^n$ using the $L_\infty$ norm, but I don't think that matters).

In this particular space, points that are less than a certain distance apart are considered "indistinguishable" (basically they're measurements that are within error margins of each other given the test that we're using).

I want to try and figure out how many points I need to sample from $D$ to get, on average, less than a chosen proportion of points that are "isolated" (only indistinguishable from themselves).

At the moment I'm doing it by simulation (sampling from a big dataset, drawing a closed ball around each point, and seeing how many points are isolated). However, it's taking a long time and I'm hoping that there's some theory to help me simplify the problem in the long run.

Someone must have done this before - I'm feeling like there's something in packing theory, some distribution that I can use to model it, stuff like that - but I don't know what papers or books to read. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you know about D?

Comment: This might be easy to answer for a uniform case, but for any other distribution I'd say this does not have any nice form.

Comment: Yeah, more I think of it, more I think that what you need is a smart algorithm to count your overlapping regions and you can't do better then that.

Comment: @ThreeDiag: I know very little about D - it's bounded to an n-dimensional cube, and there's quite a lot of correlation between adjacent dimensions (up to about r = 0.9 for some of them) but it doesn't appear to be well approximated by a multivariate normal. So yeah, I'm basically counting regions at the moment, but I'm wondering whether there are any cases that have been studied that might approximate the results that I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of a given point in a sample of size $n$ being isolated is:

$$\int f(x)(1 - G(x))^{n-1}dx$$

where $f$ is the pdf and $G(x)$ is the probability that a point is indistinguishable from $x$.

If you know $f$, maybe you can plug it in and solve numerically or analytically for how big $n$ needs to be to get this probability below your target proportion.

Comment: This doesn't seem to get us very far towards a solution, because the problem is more complex than analyzing a "given point." Are you perhaps hinting that you know a way to exploit your formulation to help solve the problem that has been asked?

Comment: The question was to bound the average proportion of points in the sample that are isolated. If the probability of the $i$-th point in the sample being isolated is $< p$ for each $i$, doesn't that imply that the expected proportion of isolated points in the sample is also $< p$, by linearity of expectation?